# EditText layout_height oddity

Tags: android

I've observed a strange thing about EditText widgets. If you adjust the layout_height downwards, say, to 36dp, the background of the widget exhibits bars above and below the text.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="hh:mmAM" >
</EditText>
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: example screen capture]

The gray bars above and below the time should be one solid gray area. In fact, they do become one solid gray area when layout_height reaches 48dp. As you adjust the height toward 48dp, the gap between the gray bars becomes narrower and narrower. Is there an explanation for this behavior, or is this an Android bug? Is there a workaround?

I should add that I'm working with a 480x800 screen (Nexus S).

Comment: Setting layout_height on an EditText to anything but wrap_content is a terrible idea from a usability perspective. I suspect this behavior is due to the way the background image (provided by the framework) of the EditText scales when it is reduced to a height that is smaller than the image's height.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no choice. My screen design mandates that I reduce the size of the EditText fields so that they fit within smaller screens, such as HVGA. (The screen design was originally done on the Nexus S, ie, WVGA.) To suggest that you may not reduce the layout height in order to accommodate screen design is idiotic; a designer MUST be given the flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like 9patch problem.
when 9patch image attached to a view that's height is smaller than 9patch needed it looks like your case, because the minimum size needed for 9patch to look properly due to 9patch have 'not stretchable area'.

Comment: If you must set edittext height to smaller than 48dp you can change edittext's background to your own 9patch image.